# How to map multiple df with specific column and keep the old mapped data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Have two dataframes with

```
# create sample dataframes
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Alice"],
    "age": [25],
    "status": ["Single"]
})
```

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Alice", "Charlie", "Dave"],
    "time": ["9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM"]
})
```

creating  a dictionary mapping the "name" column to the "status" column in df_1

```
status_map = dict(zip(df_1["name"], df_1["status"]))
```

using the map() function to map the "status" column in df_2 based on the "name" column

```
df_2["status"] = df_2["name"].map(status_map)
```

Got this output:

```
      name      time   status
0    Alice   9:00 AM   Single
1  Charlie  10:00 AM      NaN
2     Dave  11:00 AM      NaN
```

If i try to update status using other df. exisitng data is getting overwritten

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Dave"],
    "age": [25],
    "status": ["Married"]
})
```

```
status_map_df3 = dict(zip(df_3["name"], df_3["status"]))
df_2["status"] = df_2["name"].map(status_map_df3)
```

Output:

```
      name      time   status
0    Alice   9:00 AM      NaN
1  Charlie  10:00 AM      NaN
2     Dave  11:00 AM  Married
```

How to keep both status on the df

required output

```
      name      time   status
0    Alice   9:00 AM   Single
1  Charlie  10:00 AM      NaN
2     Dave  11:00 AM  Married
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have the column, you can use `fillna`:

```
df_2["status"] = df_2["status"].fillna(df_2["name"].map(status_map_df3))
print(df_2)

# Output
      name      time   status
0    Alice   9:00 AM   Single
1  Charlie  10:00 AM      NaN
2     Dave  11:00 AM  Married
```

If you want to use the same technique for `df_1` and `df_3`, create an empty column in `df_2`:

```
df_2["Status"] = np.nan

# Use update instead of fillna if you want
# to update values even if ones already exist
df_2["Status"].update(df_2["name"].map(status_map))
df_2["Status"].update(df_2["name"].map(status_map_df3))
print(df_2)

# Output
      name      time   Status
0    Alice   9:00 AM   Single
1  Charlie  10:00 AM      NaN
2     Dave  11:00 AM  Married
```